# getting insufficient permissions while creating google calendar event

Tags: google-apps

I am trying a create an google calendar event using API...But i am getting error while trying to create event..I am getting access token succesfully but not able to create calendar events...

Please help i am trying to sort out this from the last 2 days...I think this is some perrmision issue...I am using below scope.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
String scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

Http h = new Http();
String calendarId='gdrivema...@gmail.com';
String url='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'+calendarId+'/events';
String body='{"end":{"date": "2013-06-21"},"start":{"date": "2013-06-20"}}';

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
System.debug('-----accesstokenvvvvvvvv---'+accesstoken);
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accesstoken);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setBody(body);

System.debug('-----body---'+body);
req.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse res;
res = h.send(req);
String data = res.getBody();
System.debug('--------data----'+data);
```

I am getting the following error in response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
        "message": "Insufficient Permission"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
  }
}
```